# C++/Qt: how to access windows registry remotely?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry

does anyone have a clue how I can read values from the windows registry of a remote host (presuming I have sufficient rights). I mean by software/ my own written code. I need this for my tool e.g. to get a list of installed software on that machine.

Is this possible in C,C++, or even Qt?
Do I have to use some MSDN commands?

**Please see new questions below; 32-bit <-> 64-bit problem.**

Comment: Is this for a corporate enviroment, arbitrary private users, ...?

Comment: @Georg: Hi! It is for corporate environment. Why are you asking? ;)

Comment: I was asking because in a controlled corporate enviroment it might be fine to directly do that, while "out in the wild" security concerns etc. arise.

Comment: @Georg: You mean on the internet? :) Just seen that my introduction somehow get lost which makes my post seem somehow informal and impolite. :D

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [RegConnectRegistry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in MSDN. This allows you to open a handle to a remote registry key and then use the standard registry APIs to interact with it.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the hint. I will have a try! I hope I'll find something/ get it running on my own.

Comment: I was successful with RegConnectRegistry, RegOpenKeyEx, RegEnumKeyEx and RegQueryInfoKey so far. Just wondering if I should use RegGetValue or RegQueryValueEx now.

Comment: Ok, finally I got it working so far with RegQueryValueEx. I especially liked this site:
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=370253